# new line for nodes JS

Tags: node.js, line-breaks

I have been trying to figure where to put \r\n to put breakline to my code. The code below gives me output of

```
Enter ID:  ID1234Enter Name: John DoeEnter Phone: 12345
```

My desired output is

```
Enter ID: ID1234
Enter Name: John Doe
Enter Phone: 12345
```

HTML

```
<input type="text "class="unique" size="9" value="Enter ID: " readonly/>
  <input type="text "class="unique" size="15" value=" " > <br>
  <input type="text "class="unique" size="9" value="Enter Name: " readonly/>
  <input type="text "class="unique" size="15" value="" > <br>
  <input type="text "class="unique" size="9" value="Enter Phone: " readonly/>
  <input type="text "class="unique" size="15" value="" > <br>

  <button id="copybtn" onclick="doCopy()"> Copy to clipboard </button>
```

JS

```
function doCopy() {

try{
var unique = document.querySelectorAll('.unique');
var msg ="";

unique.forEach(function (unique) {
msg+=unique.value;

});

var temp =document.createElement("textarea");
var tempMsg = document.createTextNode(msg);
temp.appendChild(tempMsg);

document.body.appendChild(temp);
temp.select();

document.execCommand("copy");
document.body.removeChild(temp);
console.log("Success!")

}
catch(err) {

console.log("There was an error copying");
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `forEach` for joining the strings in your `unique` array. You can use [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead, which let's you specify a “glue” string that is put in between (in your case, a line break):

```
var unique = document.querySelectorAll('.unique');
var msg = unique.join("\r\n");
```